# tinymce custom implementation - their docAPI could be better

Tags: javascript, tinymce

i'm just trying user to be able to insert, `<p>, <ul> & <li> and <img>`, how can i do it?

their webiste it's too confusing for me...

anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to adjust the `theme_advanced_buttons` settings:

```
tinyMCE.init({
    //...
    theme_advanced_buttons1: 'bullist,numlist,image',
    theme_advanced_buttons2: '',
    theme_advanced_buttons3: '',
    theme_advanced_buttons4: '',
    //...
});
```

AFAIK, you always get paragraphs.

Have a look at [these examples](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/tryit/full.php) for more, there are various examples listed in the right sidebar.

Comment: @Toni Michel Caubet: "AFAIK" == "As Far As I Know", paragraphs should always be available in TinyMCE. Leave 2,3,4 as empty strings unless you want more than one toolbar.

Comment: If you don't put an empty string in buttons 2 & 3 then you will get the default toolbar button list for those toolbars. I'm pretty sure you don't need button4 as there isn't a default for it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer...

```
var Editor = tinyMCE.get('YourEditorID');
Editor.focus();
Editor.selection.setContent('<strong>Hello World</strong>');
```

Note: focus() may not be needed, depending on situation.

Comment: but where is the customization?